# using require.js, can you (a) define a simple plugin (b) show how to use that plugin from a client perspective?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require

Based on the documentation,

Here is a basic plugin definition:

```
define({
    load: function (name, req, onload, config) {
        //req has the same API as require().
        req([name], function (value) {
            console.log('plugin loaded');
            onload(value);
        });
    }
});
```

However, when I 'require' the plugin -- (seen below), I do not see the 'load' method getting called.

```
require(["myPlugin"], function(plugin) {
         console.log('after plugin has loaded');       
});
```

I'm clearly missing something here -- can anyone suggest?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: RequireJS has great docs: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define

Comment: the code that i included is straight from the link you provided above.   Can you tell me if there is something that calls the plugin lifecycle methods such as 'load'.  that is the problem -- i am expecting some container or manager to invoke the load method and it's other methods that all plugins should have.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to load a plugin you must have an exclamation point after the plugin name. If you issue require like this, it will work:

```
require(["myPlugin!"], function(plugin) {
```

I've tested it with your code. No problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, I think the question I am trying to ask is -- how can I get require.js to acknowledge the module as a require.js plugin?   -- the check for correctness would be if you can load 'myPlugin', and have it's 'load' method called by the require.js framework.

Comment: When I wrote "I've tested it with your code. No problem." it implied that RequireJS called the ``load`` method.